# Will the fee for "bitcoin.it" decrease as the value of BTC increases?

Tags: bitcoin-wiki

I'm interested in contributing technical information to the Wiki page located on https://en.bitcoin.it  however they require editors to donate   0.01 BTC at the following page.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Special:BitcoinPayment

I'm not interested in spending $2 just to share research that I've worked hard on... and I think it has been this value was less than $1 when the feature was first implemented.

- Will the donation value of 0.01 BTC decrease in time?

Answer (score 2):

That may full depend on owners of the site, however you can still send them email containing your research, and thay may accept it to that site without payment.